# Program skips over System.in

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a program to call another code that creates an RPN Calculator

```
        RPNCalculator Calculator = new RPNCalculator();
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid post-fix expression one token " +
                    "at a time with a space between each token (e.g. 5 4 + 3 2 1 - + *)");
        System.out.println("Each token must be an integer or an operator (+,-,*,/)");
        Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("That expression equals " + result);
        System.out.println();

    while (true)
    {    
         equation = reader.nextLine();
         result=Calculator.evaluateEquation(equation);
    }
```

However when the program runs, it does not even give the chance to input anything and will return "That expression equals 0"

Comment: Your prints are before your read loop. You realize that `new Scanner(System.in)` merely says "create a scanner that, when you call its `next...` methods, will be reading from the `System.in`"

Comment: Compile error: `result cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Compile error: `equation cannot be resolved to a variable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your while loop on the wrong side of the System.out.println()'s.

```
Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
while (true)
{    
     equation = reader.nextLine();  
     //YOU ALSO need a reason to break out of this loop.
     //LIKE IF equation == "EXIT" or "0"
         //BREAK
     result=Calculator.evaluateEquation(equation);
}   
System.out.println();
System.out.println("That expression equals " + result);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have an issue with the stack being empty after the first run through, but I should probably save that for another question.

Comment: @jake94b you should mark this answer correct.  So others can find in the future.